# Send asp.net requests to a 3rd party server programmatically?

Tags: asp.net

ASP.NET noob here and would like to see whether it's feasible to do something like this before spending too much time looking into it.

So I have an account with an insurance company web portal, the website is built in ASP.NET. Normally, after I log in, I'd need to manually fill out a webform, then click a button to receive quote information for a particular client.

I am wondering whether it's possible to automate this process.
I can see the requests being made, however, all the 'VIEWSTATE' is encoded and I've tried to decode it using some online decoders, but none have worked so far.
I also see 'EVENTVALIDATION', I am not sure if it's something to do with the traffic encryption.

Generally speaking, is it even realistic to programmatically send/receive reqs/resps to a web server like this?

Thank you!

Comment: It is unclear where a “third party” fits in. If it is about “automating a website interaction as a user would” than ASP.NET has no real bearing on question other than to indicate that the automation does not include an exposed API.

Comment: And yes, there are tools to automate website interactions. These generally run “as a browser would”. One popular example for further research is Selenium. Another term to search for is “web scraping”, as the end goal appears to retrieve a quote.

Comment: It is not practical to otherwise deal with the VIEWSTATE manually. It is also *encrypted and signed*. Thus there is no need to even consider that level of approach here.

Comment: Or, perhaps this said insurance company offers external API services for agents (?? etc.) that can be accessed through an officially supported channel..

Comment: Thanks so much @user2864740 for deciphering my questions so precisely. I had no idea something like Selenium existed. I would definitely look into this.

Comment: Good suggestion too about reaching out to the company about the api service, I would give it a try although I very much doubt they would have any.